# How can I fix this problem with bulding project at Vitis?

Tags: include, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I'm trying to build a project with vitis using the library *xuartps.h* but I can't because of this error
[code screenchot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jvl9.png)

I don't know why this happens. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

This is an include file. It gets literally copy-pasted on your sources. On top of that, the compiler could notify the error around the wrong line, but it could be before or after the one which is actually wrong.

Check your sources that include such header, you must miss a semicolon there, or another typo. You should not look into the header.